# Angular change input value and display

Tags: angular

I have an input like

```
<mat-form-field>
      <input id="filter_administrationTable_{{ componentName }}" matInput
             (keyup)="administrationTableFilter($event.target.value)" placeholder="{{ filterLabel }}">
    </mat-form-field>
```

This is used as a filter to a table. After updating my data table, I would like to clear value of filter and clear it in frontend as well. How do I do it in Angular?

Comment: can you add some more code and explanation?

Comment: Do you want to reset the input field?

Comment: What is the value of filter? Where are you binding that value? Whats inside the administrationTableFilter() function to change that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was enough to use `[(ngModel)]="filterValue"` and clear it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Clearing an input text field in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41483914/clearing-an-input-text-field-in-angular2) where they use `[value]` property binding and "Clear" button as a solution to this.